# Assistance with misspelled tag

Tags: support

The *deliverability* tag (misspelled: deliverabiilty): https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deliverabiilty - could use some TLC, or at least some spell checking.

As I don't yet have enough reputation to do this myself, can someone more privileged have a look? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I renamed the tag `deliverabiilty` to `deliverability`. The old tag is remapped to the correctly-spelled version. Thanks for the heads-up!